# How to commit on Github and automatically mark done on Basecamp?

Tags: github, version-control, basecamp

I have a GitHub account and Basecamp account. I have already setup my GitHub to use Basecamp service hook by selecting `Service Hooks Menu` and `select basecamp`. Fill all required form and get the setup work properly identified by green color.

Now, I have `to-do list` at my Basecamp account, but I don't know how to interact between GitHub commit comment and Basecamp to-do list.

For example, I commit my code by commenting `fixing to-do list #123`. But on Basecamp, I can't find to-do list ID (ex:#123) like common project management that I use before. I also can't find a documentation about it.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have send a same question to both github and basecamp support and bellow they answer.

### Basecamp Support:

> Sorry about that confusion with the GitHub integration! At the moment,
>   that integration only brings in the commits you make into the Progress
>   page and recaps. Here's the code behind that integration so you can
>   get a better idea of the guts of that service hook:
>
> https://github.com/github/github-services/blob/master/services/basecamp.rb
>
> If you have any other questions, just let me know and I'll be happy to
>   help. And have an awesome Sunday!
>
> Chase Clemons
>  37signals CustomerCare

### Github Support:

> The Basecamp hook is for the new Basecamp system, and only adds to a
>   project's event log.  There is a Basecamp Classic hook for the older
>   Basecamp system.  It looks like that hook only creates Basecamp
>   messages.  It doesn't look like anyone has written any Basecamp to-do
>   integration with GitHub at this time.  Our 3rd party hooks are
>   contributed by other users because we don't actually use any of those
>   services (Basecamp included).  You're welcome to contribute to them:
>
> https://github.com/github/github-services

So it's clear at the moment (when I write this), what we commit and push into Github repository just automatically show on Basecamp Progress page.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that's possible with the existing github-basecamp integration (the one in the predefined service hooks). So, in short: if I'm correct, it cannot be done [the way you can close github issues](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation), which you also seem to be referring.

So basically you'd need to do some coding of your own. You have two main choices.

1. You can enable a [webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-webhooks) in your github service hooks, have that do a POST request to an url of your choice, and have a script at that url use [basecamp API](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api) to update the list. The [todolists api](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/todolists.md) seems quite simple: you should read a commit message coming in the POST request, and do a "update todolist" request with `"completed": true`.
2. Another alternative is to interact with Basecamp API from your local repo. There seems to be some existing tool called [gitcamp](https://github.com/pdclark/Gitcamp), made by someone, to help with that - however as the api is quite simple, as well as your requirement, you could do your stuff with a custom script installed as a hook, and possibly with more ease.